# TypeError - Client error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, network-programming

I created a Client/Server code in python. Server works well and get listen on 8000 port, but when I connect to it via client and then I try to send a message to server I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\milad\workspace\NetworkProgramming\client.py", line 26, in <module>
    if __name__ == "__main__" : main()
  File "C:\Users\milad\workspace\NetworkProgramming\client.py", line 20, in main
    TcpSocket.send(sendData)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

I don't know how can I fix this problem about the client code. In the following I put the client code. I written it with Python language.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import socket
from builtins import input

def main():
    serverHostNumber = input("Please enter the ip address of the server: \n")
    serverPortNumber = input("Please enter the port of the server: \n")

    # create a socket object
    TcpSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

    # connection to hostname on the port.
    TcpSocket.connect((serverHostNumber, int(serverPortNumber)))                                                                    

    while True:
        data = TcpSocket.recv(1024)
        print("Server : ", data)
        sendData = str(input("Client : "))
        TcpSocket.send(sendData)



    TcpSocket.close()

if __name__ == "__main__" : main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    TcpSocket.send(sendData)
```

Looks like [`send`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send) accepts only `bytes` instances. Try:

```
    TcpSocket.send(bytes(sendData, "ascii")) #... or whatever encoding is appropriate
```

Answer (score 0):

The python 2 documentation for the sockets class shows the .send function/method accepting a string parameter - but if you look at the [python 3 documentation for the same class](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/socket.html) you'll see that .send now requires the data to be passed as a parameter of type bytearray.

Changing:

```
sendData = str(input("Client : "))
```

to

```
sendData = str.encode(input("Client : "))
```

should do the trick, I believe.