# Python 3.5 socket package error for send

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

I was taking courses of Python from Coursera. I was trying to run the following sample code provided in the slides using Python 3.5:

```
import socket
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('www.py4inf.com', 80))
mysock.send('GET http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n')
```

But instead I received this error:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Does anybody know how to fix this? I guess it might be due to the version of Python. The course was using Python 2.X.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [TypeError - Client error in python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32589771/2006429)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/socket.html?highlight=socket.socket#socket.socket.send). It states that `send` takes a `bytes` parameter. You are passing a `str`. That is also the exact same thing the error message says.

To make your example work use a `bytes` literal:

```
mysock.send(b'GET http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n')
```

notice the **b** in front of the `'`

Our you can [encode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) your string:

```
mysock.send('GET http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n'.encode())
```

**EDIT:**

You are right: in python 2 `socket.send` expects a `str` as can be seen [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html?highlight=socket.socket#socket.socket.send)